# replace string from one file to another awk

Tags: bash, awk, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to search and replace string from a yaml file that I use for helm values. I have used the following command to extract the values that are different between two files:

```
diff a.yaml b.yaml|grep ">"|cut -c 3- > new_file.yaml
```

The a.yaml file contains the following lines:

```
NAME_VAR: {{ .Data.data.name_var }}
SOME_VALUE: {{ .Data.data.some_value }}
ONE_MORE: {{ .Data.data.one_more }}
```

and b.yaml this:

```
NAME_VAR: {{ .Data.data.name_var }}
SOME_VALUE: {{ .Data.data.some_value }}
ONE_MORE: {{ .Data.data.one_more }}
ADD_THIS: {{ .Data.data.<change_me> }}
```

The output in new_file.yaml gives me the following:

```
ADD_THIS: {{ .Data.data.<change_me> }}
```

I need to replace the string inside <change_me> with the key of the output "ADD_THIS" it should look like this:

```
ADD_THIS: {{ .Data.data.add_this }}
```

These changes will be updated with vault later automatically in argocd.

I've thought about using awk but I can't seem to replace it.....

**Edit**

In case you want to replace several fields, e.g.

a.yaml file

```
NAME_VAR: {{ .Data.data.name_var }}
SOME_VALUE: {{ .Data.data.some_value }}
ONE_MORE: {{ .Data.data.one_more }}
```

b.yaml file

```
NAME_VAR: {{ .Data.data.name_var }}
SOME_VALUE: {{ .Data.data. }}
ONE_MORE: {{ .Data.data. }}
ADD_THIS: {{ .Data.data. }}
```

Using James' answer this is the output:

```
ADD_THIS: {{ .Data.data.add_this }}
SOME_VALUE: {{ .Data.data.some_value }}
ONE_MORE: {{ .Data.data.one_more }}
SOME_VALUE: {{ .Data.data.some_value }}
ONE_MORE: {{ .Data.data.one_more }}
```

Comment: If you already have a placeholder like `<change_me>` in `b.yaml` then why do you need `a.yaml`?

Comment: Given Helm's templating capabilities, do you actually need `awk` for this?  It's a little hard to tell what values you intend to use and what should get sent to Kubernetes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An awk that frees you from using `diff` and `grep` and `cut`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{       # process first file, which ever
    a[$0]             # hash records to a 
    next              # on to the next record
}
{                     # process second file
    if($0 in a)       # if record is in hash (or file 1)
        delete a[$0]  # remove it from the hash as it is not wanted
    else              # if record is not in hash (or file 1)
        a[$0]         # store it to the hash as it is wanted
}
END {                 # in the end all wanted records are left in the hash
    for(i in a) {     # go thru all of them
        $0=i
        sub(/<change_me>/,substr(tolower($1),1,length($1)-1))
        print         # make the change (above) and output
    }
}' [ab].yaml
```

Output:

```
ADD_THIS: {{ .Data.data.add_this }}
```

You could replace the `sub` above with

```
sub(/[^.]*$/,substr(tolower($1),1,length($1)-1),$3)
```

if the `<change_me>` is in fact an arbitrary string.

**Edit** to solve the issues mentioned in comments:

Now it stores and compares the first fields and compares them ie:

```
a[SOME_VALUE:]="SOME_VALUE: {{ .Data.data.some_value }}"
```

Program now:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {
    a[$1]=$0
    next
}
{
    if($1 in a)
        delete a[$1]
    else
        a[$1]=$0
}
END {
    for(i in a) {
        $0=a[i]
        sub(/[^.]*$/,substr(tolower($1),1,length($1)-1),$3)
        print
    }
}' [ab].yaml
```

Comment: Yes, it is an arbitrary string. Thank you very much! even though all the answers are valid and have solved other doubts for me

Comment: If I try to replace several, it repeats a line for me, should this be its behaviour?
`ADD_THIS: {{ .Data.data.add_this }}
ONE_MORE: {{ .Data.data.one_more }}
ONE_MORE: {{ .Data.data.one_more }} `

Comment: But in a nutshell, it finds the lines that are not in the other file, edits and outputs them.

Comment: I commented the code, maybe you understand better how it works.

Comment: The extra lines are output as their values differ (for example `SOME_VALUE:` has `.Data.data.some_value` and just `.Data.data.` in the other file and the program compares full strings. I can fix that, gimme a sec.

Comment: Fixed it. Better?

Comment: Yes, but now I only get one value, if I want to change more than one, can I save all the differences? Then replace .Data.data.<some_value> in as many as I need

Comment: This is getting out of hands. Please make a new question with extensive sample data and desired behavior. Also, link this question to it. Others will step up, I need to go to bed, it's past midnight over here.

Answer (score 2):

Better use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) for this particular task:

```
$ sed 's/<change_me>/add_this/' file
ADD_THIS: {{ .Data.data.add_this }}
```

Answer (score 1):

This takes the value of the first column, lowers it, also removes the colon, then does the replacement.

```
$ awk '{str = tolower($1)
        sub(":", "", str)
        sub("<change_me>", str, $0)}1' new_file.yaml
ADD_THIS: {{ .Data.data.add_this }}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the first column output can be other key values and/or the place holder can vary away from 'change me', awk can use variable names to reference them.

This demo uses an echo to feed the output into awk but the same awk procedure would process a multi-line file with many lines to be substituted, and is not dependent on the key value nor the place holder text.

```
echo "ADD_THIS: {{ .Data.data.<change_me> }}" | awk ' {n=split($3,parts,"."); sub(parts[n],tolower($1), $3); print $0} ';
```

result:

```
ADD_THIS: {{ .Data.data.add_this: }}
```